# How to remove intermediate values in SQL without any stored procedures or functions?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with some of the report generation scripts where I have gone this scenario where I have no idea how to do this since I am very new to SQL.

**Original Data**

[image: Original data]

**Expected Output**

[image]

Any Suggestion will be highly appreciable Thanks in advance!

Comment: What will be the condition to get expected output from your Original Data! Can you please write some more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  The problem is getting the appropriate ordering, and `row_number()` can help there:

```
select fieldname,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then oldvalue end) as oldvalue,
       max(case when seqnum = cnt then newvalue end) as newvalue
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from t
     ) t
group by fieldname;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your id is and incremental int (i.e. identity)

```
Declare @Table table (id int,FieldName varchar(25),OldValue varchar(20),NewValue varchar(25))
Insert into @Table (id,FieldName,OldValue,NewValue) values 
(1,'MI','M','N'),
(2,'GENDER','Male','Female'),
(3,'GENDER','Female','Male'),
(4,'FIRSTNAME','','J'),
(5,'FIRSTNAME','J','Joh'),
(6,'FIRSTNAME','Joh','John'),
(7,'STATE','','NJ'),
(8,'COUNTRY','US','USA')


Select Sequence = min(MinRow)
      ,A.FieldName
      ,OldValue = max(case when id=B.MinRow then OldValue else null end)
      ,NewValue = max(case when id=B.MaxRow then NewValue else null end)
 From  @Table A
 Join (Select FieldName,MinRow=min(ID),MaxRow=max(ID) From @Table Group by FieldName) B on A.FieldName=B.FieldName
 Group by A.FieldName
 Order by 1
```

Returns

```
Sequence    FieldName   OldValue    NewValue
1           MI          M           N
2           GENDER      Male        Male
4           FIRSTNAME               John
7           STATE                   NJ
8           COUNTRY     US          USA
```

Added the Sequence and Order By so

Answer (score 1):

This should yield the correct results using fairly basic SQL:

```
SELECT
    mc1.FieldName,
    mc2.OldValue, -- OldestValue would perhaps be more meaningful
    mc3.NewValue -- Likewise, NewestValue here.
FROM (
    SELECT FieldName, MIN(Id) MinId, MAX(Id) MaxId
    FROM ModelChange
    GROUP BY FieldName
) mc1
INNER JOIN ModelChange mc2 ON mc1.MinId = mc2.Id
INNER JOIN ModelChange mc3 ON mc1.MaxId = mc3.Id;
```

I've made the assumption that your Id is incremental and that the oldest value for a given FieldName will have the minimum Id and that the newest value will have the maximum Id.